# Making a 3D plot of $x\,y$ that looks like the one I get from Maple

Tags: plotting, maple

I made a 3D plot of $x\,y$ in Maple:

```
plot3d(x*y, grid = [10, 10], color = "Red", style = pointline,axes = framed)
```

[image]

How can I make the same graphic in *Mathematica*? I tried the basic

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

but don't how to modify it to get the look I want.

Comment: No points, but I'm sure you'll have no trouble adding them in: `Plot3D[x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, BoundaryStyle -> Red, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None]`

Comment: @J.M. there are more lines $17\times 17$ instead  $10\times 10$ how to change it?

Comment: Add `Mesh -> 8`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[Plot3D[x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, BoundaryStyle -> Red, 
  MeshStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 8, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}], 
 ListPointPlot3D[
  Table[{x, y, x y}, {x, -10, 10, 2 + 2/9}, {y, -10, 10, 2 + 2/9}], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, PointSize[0.015]}}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
ListPlot3D[Table[x y, {x,0, 10}, {y,0, 10}], Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, MeshShading -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Red,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

Or with `Plot3D`

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> Red, 
MeshShading -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
Boxed -> False, BoundaryStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot `BoundaryStyle -> Red`.

Comment: Thanks @J.M. (and also `AxesLabel`)